# What is the typical file size for a 3d render of a house?

Tags: android, google-project-tango

I am wondering if anyone has any info on how large of a file a typical render is. For example, how large is a full 3d map for a house or what is the square foot to megabyte ratio?

Comment: square foot? does that hurt?

Answer (score 1):

This is really depends on your algorithm and the density of the data. For example a small box can be stored as 8 points and 12 triangle faces, that is 8 * 3 * 4 bytes + 12 * 3 * 4 bytes. However, the same box can also be stored in millions of points, just with denser point aggregation.

Comment: That does beg the question of how you get from the 10Ks+ of point cloud elements to the actual wall they are looking at, i.e.solving 6 times for  ax + by + cz = d, and hence to the 6 walls that constitute you example box

Answer (score 0):

Practical experience with Tango nets out at about 33 Mb/min for picture, pose, pointcloud, and location (GPS) data -  this is basically the raw data rate you'll need to consider for input.
In the future that rate will drop, as point clouds will get processed locally before cloud upload (averaging, voxelization, etc) and the number of images will also drop (especially with on the fly texture generation).